# Unable to resolve a contradiction I get while calculating $ \frac{\partial y'}{\partial x'} $

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $ x(t) = e^{5t} $.

Let $ y(t) = f(x) = x^2 + x^3 = e^{10t} + e^{15t} $.

Then $ x'(t) = 5e^{5t} = 5x $.

And $ y'(t) = f'(x) x'(t) = (2x + 3x^2)(5x) = 10x^2 + 15x^3 = 10e^{10t} + 15e^{15t} $.

All good so far. Everything is matching up. Everything makes sense.

Now I try to calculate $ \frac{\partial y'}{\partial x'} $ and this is where everything becomes messed up for me.

Let $ u = 5x $.

Then $ x'(t) = 5x = u $.

And $ y'(t) = 10x^2 + 15x^3 = \frac{2u^2}{5} + \frac{3u^3}{25} $.

Now I calculate $ \frac{\partial y'}{\partial x'} $ using one method:

$$
\frac{\partial y'}{\partial x'} 
= \frac{\partial \left( \frac{2u^2}{5} + \frac{3u^3}{25} \right)}{\partial u} 
= \frac{4u}{5} + \frac{9u^2}{25}
= 4x + 9x^2
= 4e^{5t} + 9e^{10t}.
$$

Again I calculate $ \frac{\partial y'}{\partial x'} $ using another method:

$$
\frac{\partial y'}{\partial x'}
= \frac{\partial}{\partial x'} \left( f'(x) x' \right) = f'(x) \frac{\partial x'}{\partial x'} = f'(x) = 2x + 3x^2 = 2e^{5t} + 3e^{10t}.
$$

Why does solving the same partial derivative using two different methods lead to different results? Which one is the correct result and which one is incorrect? Clearly I am missing something in my understanding of partial derivatives. If someone can help me understand which one of my two results (or both?) are incorrect, it will also help me to understand partial derivatives better.

Comment: Why is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x'}(f'(x)x')=f'(x)\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x'}$ and not $\frac{\partial}{\partial x'}(f'(x)x')=\frac{\partial}{\partial x'}(f'(x))x'+f'(x)\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x'}$? What allows you to drop the first term in the "derivative of product", in other words?

Comment: Your misusage of partial derivative symbols makes error.
$\frac{dy'}{dx'}=\frac{d}{dx'}(f'(x)x')=$ $f''(x)\frac{dx}{dx'}x'+f'(x)=$ $f''(x)\frac{d(u/5)}{du}x'+f'(x)=$ $f''(x)/5+f'(x)=(2+6x)/5 x'+(2x+3x^2)=$ $(2+6x)x+(2x+3x^2)=4x+9x^2$. Usage of partial derivative is not correct when there is only one independent variable ($t$).